# CI_session is not saving in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-cookies

My system can't login when I use Mozilla Firefox. 
I tried logging in without requiring session and I successfuly enter in my system. I think Mozilla is not saving the session. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if the cookies are enabled in your Mozilla browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function login_user(){
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'pass' => $this->input->post('pass')
    );

    if($data['name'] == 'test' and $data['pass'] == 'test' ){
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_name','test');
        return redirect('cicrud/Post');
    } else {
        return redirect('cicrud/login');
    }
}
```

please refer this code

and type this code in your view file and check the this is show in the 'Test' out put

```
$this->session->userdata('user_name')
```

this is not the Mozilla Firefox browser issue.
can you please share your code then we check out the what is the issue.

Comment: have you loaded the session library in each page or in autoload.php?

Comment: i use the autoload.php file